# How do I remove multiple empty lines in a text file

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if someone is able to help. I have a m3u file with multiple lines of formatted text.

```
#EXTM3U
#RADIOBROWSERUUID:963194ef-0601-11e8-ae97-52543be04c81
#EXTINF:1,80s80s Christmas
http://streams.80s80s.de/christmas/mp3-192/streams.80s80s.de/

#RADIOBROWSERUUID:9638cfa5-0601-11e8-ae97-52543be04c81
#EXTINF:1,181.FM - Christmas Kountry
http://www.181.fm/stream/pls/181-xkkountry.pls
```

Whilst I have managed to extract the data into a format that I can need... I am left with multiple blank lines. A sample bit of code I used to Extract the data is...

```
                If line.StartsWith("#EXTM3U") Then 'Remove
                    lines(i) = ""
                End If
                If line.StartsWith("#RADIOBROWSERUUID:") Then 'Remove
                    lines(i) = ""
                End If
                If line.StartsWith("#EXTINF:1,") Then 'Add # at beginning of line
                    lines(i) = line.Replace("#EXTINF:1,", "#") 
                End If
```

Which then leaves me with the following...

```
#80s80s Christmas
@http://streams.80s80s.de/christmas/mp3-192/streams.80s80s.de/


#181.FM - Christmas Kountry
@http://www.181.fm/stream/pls/181-xkkountry.pls
```

I just dont seem to be able to remove the empty/blank lines. I have used google as well as here and non of the answers seem to work for me. Here is the code that I am using...

```
Dim Newlines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)

For t As Integer = 0 To Newlines.Length - 1
Dim line2 As String = Newlines(t)
If line2.StartsWith("") Then ' Remove blank lines
Beep()
Newlines(t) = line2.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty)  
End If
Next

File.WriteAllLines("NewTextm3u.txt", lines)
```

Can any body see where I am going wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Visual Studio, so I've edited that out of the title and removed the tag. Your question is strictly about VB.Net; the IDE or editor being used has nothing to do with it.

Comment: When deleting items in a loop, you need to start at the bottom and work your way up, because you're removing items. Reverse your loop that deletes the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
   Dim sFile As String = "c:\test2\test2.txt"

    Dim Fdata As New List(Of String)

    Fdata = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test2\test.txt").ToList

    For i = Fdata.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Fdata(i) = "" Then
            Fdata.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

    For Each sLine As String In Fdata
        Debug.Print(sLine)
    Next

    File.WriteAllLines(sFile)
```

The above would remove all blank lines

In place of that loop, you could also use lamda expression like this:

```
    Fdata.RemoveAll(Function(MyOneRow) MyOneRow = "")
```

Comment: Your first section of code worked a treat thank you very much, and thank you everyone else

Answer (score 1):

I used the `StrignSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to get rid of blank lines.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim FileContents = File.ReadAllText("SomeFile.txt")
    Dim lines = FileContents.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there is what we can call an "enter" at the end of the sentence and another one between.
So let's just remove the one between the sentences and because it's just a line you can do it like this:

```
If line(i) = CHR(13) & CHR(10) then line(i)=""
```

but if you want to get a little paranoid and just want to remove all the "enters" or "line breaks" just do it like this:

```
 line(i)=Replace(line(i),CHR(13) & CHR(10),"")
```

Comment: I did try this line of code but it gave an "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

Comment: If you're really removing the line then you need to go backwards:
For t As Integer = Newlines.Length - 1 to 0 step -1

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I managed to solve it.